# How can I install bash package to OpenWrt without access to Internet?

Tags: bash, openwrt

I need to run a script in bash, and the only way to install bash package to OpenWrt that I have found now is "opkg install bash" , but I don't have Internet access for my router, for which I want to install the package. How can I find the off-line package then how can I install that on the router?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [OPKG Package Manager documentation](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/opkg) section on the `install` argument (under the heading "[Package manipulation](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/opkg#package_manipulation)")

`opkg` can install package files from both remote and local locations, as in:

```
opkg install http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/packages/hiawatha_7.7-2_ar71xx.ipk
opkg install /tmp/hiawatha_7.7-2_ar71xx.ipk
```

The latter is (I believe) what you want. This enables you to download the package file for `bash` on another host, put it on the local filesystem of the OpenWRT device (perhaps using `ssh`/`scp` over a direct ethernet link), and then `opkg install /path/to/package.ipk`, without having it need to connect to the Internet.